# highlight both page and matching tab in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I have a tab navigation link(tab1, tab2, tab3) and the bottom of the page there is a page link navigation for each tabs.

**for tabs highlight**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var str=location.href.toLowerCase();
     $(".tabs li a").each(function() {
         if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1  ) {
            $("li.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
            $(this).parent().addClass("highlight");
         }
      });
})
```

**for page highlight**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var str=location.href.toLowerCase();
   $(".paging li a").each(function() {
      if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1  ) {
        $("li.hp").removeClass("hp");
        $(this).parent().addClass("hp");
      }
    });            
 })
```

although a page link and a tab link were highlighted correctly for each functions how can i highlight current tab(after clicking page link) and current page at once? can i use above functions?

thanks!

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for better explanation of what you want and whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use same functions just bind a function to call the above functions to the page link tag
give an id to an html element 
eg `<Div id="myId"></Div>`
and try this

```
$("myId").live('click',function(){
  // call whichever function you want to
 }) ;
```

Comment: check above I modified the answer